# Google + API's Deprecated

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-plus

Are these list of following API's also are deprecated ?

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.agerange.read

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.language.read

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read

Answer (score 5):

Those are not apis those are [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) and no they are not deprecated.  Those scopes will continue to work with the APIs they where designed to work with.

Note: Scopes define the extent of granted access to a given API during the authorization process.  When using an api your access to that api is limited to the permissions granted by the scope you requested when you authenticated and authorized the user.

**What is actually deprecated**

> The most commonly used APIs that are being shut down include:
>
> - Google+ REST API
> - Google+ Web API
> - Google+ Android SDK
> - Google+ Domains API
> - Google+ Pages API
>
> As part of these changes:
>
> - Beginning March 7, all OAuth token requests with scopes starting with "plus." (i.e. "plus.me", "plus.login", "plus.profile.emails.read", etc) will fail upon request, and may start to intermittently fail as early as February 15, 2019.
> - The Google+ Sign-in feature has been fully deprecated and will also be shut down on March 7, 2019. Developers should migrate to the more comprehensive Google Sign-in authentication system.
> - Over the Air Installs is now deprecated and has been shut down.

You can read all about the deprecation here [Google+ API Shutdown](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown)